# Failed to start bitcoind using Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: bitcoind

I keep getting this error when I run sudo systemctl start bitcoind.service
Job for bitcoind.service failed because the control process exited with error code.

See "systemctl status bitcoind.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
When I input sudo journalctl -xe I get this.

```
░░ The job identifier is 6033.
abr 15 16:16:36 sats-desktop bitcoind[7207]: Error: Error parsing command line arguments: Invalid parameter -daemonwait
abr 15 16:16:36 sats-desktop systemd[1]: bitcoind.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░ 
░░
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit bitcoind.service has exited.
░░
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
abr 15 16:16:36 sats-desktop systemd[1]: bitcoind.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ ░░ The unit bitcoind.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
abr 15 16:16:36 sats-desktop systemd[1]: Failed to start Bitcoin daemon.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit bitcoind.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ ░░ A start job for unit bitcoind.service has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 6033 and the job result is failed.
abr 15 16:16:36 sats-desktop systemd[1]: bitcoind.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
░░ Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support:  ░░ Automatic restarting of the unit bitcoind.service has been scheduled, as the result for
░░ the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
abr 15 16:16:36 sats-desktop systemd[1]: Stopped Bitcoin daemon.
░░ Subject: A stop job for unit bitcoind.service has finished
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ ░░ A stop job for unit bitcoind.service has finished.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 6113 and the job result is done.
abr 15 16:16:36 sats-desktop systemd[1]: bitcoind.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
abr 15 16:16:36 sats-desktop systemd[1]: bitcoind.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ 
░░
░░ The unit bitcoind.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
abr 15 16:16:36 sats-desktop systemd[1]: Failed to start Bitcoin daemon.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit bitcoind.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ 
░░
░░ A start job for unit bitcoind.service has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 6113 and the job result is failed.
lines 1841-1894/1894 (END)
```

When I input systemctl status bitcoind.service I get this:

```
bitcoind.service - Bitcoin daemon

Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/bitcoind.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-04-15 14:13:16 CEST; 21min ago

Process: 5604 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/bitcoind -daemonwait -pid=/run/bitcoind/bitcoind.pid -conf=/home/sats/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf -datadir=/home/sats/.bitcoin (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
abr 15 14:13:16 sats-desktop systemd[1]: bitcoind.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
abr 15 14:13:16 sats-desktop systemd[1]: Stopped Bitcoin daemon.
abr 15 14:13:16 sats-desktop systemd[1]: bitcoind.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
abr 15 14:13:16 sats-desktop systemd[1]: bitcoind.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
abr 15 14:13:16 sats-desktop systemd[1]: Failed to start Bitcoin daemon.
```

Some idea how can I solve the problem??

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you have an error in bitcoind starting options, you have `-daemonwait` instead of `-daemon`, you can check with `systemctl cat bitcoind.service`

The file to edit should be `/etc/systemd/system/bitcoind.service`

Comment: Thanks. It seems it works now.

Comment: you don't have to add another answer to thanks, you have to accept the answer (if it is correct) and eventually add an upvote with the up arrow above the 0 :)
if you want to add some comment you can do it under my answer using the link "add comment"

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/77851)